# Auto-generate scripts to create tables, indexes, etc

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, ssms

In SSMS, we can right click a database/table/index/... and select the "Script As" option to generate a drop and create script.

Is there a way to automate this script generation and drop the scripts to a temp location, rather than manually right clicking each object and generating them?

Comment: I go for the simple route: http://www.petri.co.il/scripting-database-objects-in-powershell.htm

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Objects [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/ms162169.aspx) is your answer. You can use it to accomplish this task. Here is an example to generate [Create Table Scripts](https://github.com/ati-ozgur/karkas/blob/master/codeGeneration/Karkas.CodeGenerationHelper/SmoHelpers/SmoHelper.cs).

```
    public string GetTableDescription(string pDatabaseName, string pSchemaName, string pTableName, string connectionString)
    {
        connectionString = ConnectionHelper.RemoveProviderFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));
        Database db = server.Databases[pDatabaseName];
        Table t = db.Tables[pTableName, pSchemaName];
        ScriptingOptions baseOptions = new ScriptingOptions();
        baseOptions.NoCollation = true;
        baseOptions.SchemaQualify = true;
        baseOptions.DriDefaults = true;
        baseOptions.IncludeHeaders = false;
        baseOptions.DriPrimaryKey = true;
        baseOptions.ExtendedProperties = true;
        //baseOptions.DriAll = true;
        //baseOptions.Indexes = true;
        //baseOptions.DriAllKeys = true;
        //baseOptions.SchemaQualifyForeignKeysReferences = true;
        baseOptions.EnforceScriptingOptions = true;
        StringCollection result = t.Script(baseOptions);
        return StringCreate(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell and SMO to do this - simple, efficient and customizable. Such script to script out database objects can be found [here](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2013/02/a-month-of-powershell-day-27-scripting-sql-objects/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/vincpa/1755925)

Comment: Thanks Kin! The first link did the trick. Is there a way we can automate and rename the table names in the output file. Lets say, the script generate create index commands for Table_A, I need to the keyword Table_A within the output file to Table_B, so that i can run the create scripts against table_B

Comment: You can do a search+replace or use RegEx or generate the scripts with Powershell but just append _New to the script. Many ways to do it.